# Dotnet core: What is the best way to block direct access to images via the browser?

Tags: c#, browser, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've set up a dotnet core API (on IIS8) that opens up a uploads folder for an (aurelia) application. I've opened access to that folder like this

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Configuration["ApiSettings:UploadsFolder"]),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/uploads/"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
        });
```

This works fine as the application can open the the uploaded images in the application via a URL. Now I want to block access to those images when the URL is entered directly in the browser. I've seen C# solutions but could not find a dotnet core solution.

I am using middleware to intercept requests that are send to the api. But could not manage to intercept the specific images requests via the browser and block them. The only one that is allowed to access the images should be my aurelia application on a fixed domain.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
     StringValues referer;
     context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Referer", out referer);

     // Referer will contain the full URL of the image when requested
     // via the browser. When its requested differently it will contain
     // the url of the requesting application
     if (referer.Any() && referer.First().Contains("/uploads/"))
     {
         context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
         return;
     }

     await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the best way is to block direct access to images and only allow a certain application to load the images?

Comment: I want to do something similar in my .net core app.  Where did you place the Task Invoke function and where did you call it from (if at all).  Was it in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests for static files are not hitting your middle because IIS's static file handler is handling the request before it gets to .NET Core.

Simply remove "StaticFileModule" from the "Modules" feature in IIS (either for your .NET Core website or at the server level) and the requests should come through.

Here's the official .NET Core documentation that mentions this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#considerations

**Edit**

According to the docs:

> If the IIS static file handler is enabled and the ASP.NET Core Module (ANCM) is not correctly configured (for example if web.config was not deployed), static files will be served.

Which is actually the opposite to what I mentioned above. While removing the static file handler should still fix the issue, you should also check your ANCM configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So by 'While removing the static file' you say remove the `UseFileServer`? But then the uploads folder is not available for the api anymore anymore?

When calling the direct URL via the browser (locally) though it hits the line if statement and returns the 401 but it still shows the image in the browser.

Comment: No, I mean go into IIS (inetmgr) on the server (or locally if in dev), go to the website, select "Modules", and remove "StaticFileModule". All via the GUI.

Comment: Alright, I can do that but locally (via dotnet cli) it hits my middleware but I am still unable to block the request. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Your middleware needs to be run before `UseStaticFiles` and you need to _not_ call the `next()` function if you want to block it.

Comment: Your last comment was the key! Thanks!